# Node.js nodemailer module success message but e-mail never received

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, nodemailer

I have implemented nodemailer a few time before but never encountered such a strange issue. Mainly the info says that the mail is sent but i never receive it.
For example here is the output from the server when i make API request to my mailing endpoint:

```
{ from: 'mail@gmail.com',
  to: 'my-personal-mail@gmail.com',
  subject: 'Your xx password',
  html:
   '<p>Hi, Name <br>, We received a request to reset your password. <br> Therefore your new password is: <stong>yiH5S0P43M</strong></p>' }
{ accepted: [ 'to-my-personal-mail@gmail.com' ],
  rejected: [],
  envelopeTime: 396,
  messageTime: 689,
  messageSize: 448,
  response: '250 2.0.0 OK  1571325863 25sm1485661lje.58 - gsmtp',
  envelope:
   { from: 'mail@gmail.com',
     to: [ 'my-personal-mail@gmail.com' ] },
  messageId: '<message-id-here@gmail.com>' }
```

So basically everything seems fine from the callback info message, the error message is also null but the message does not come through. Here follow my actual code implementation

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: 'mymail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'mypassword'
  }
});

const mailOptions = {
from: 'mymail@gmail.com', // sender address
to: `${docs[0].email}`, // list of receivers
subject: 'Your password', // Subject line
html: `<p>Hi, ${docs[0].first_name} <br>, We received a request to reset your password. <br> Therefore your new password is: <stong>${new_password}</strong></p>`
};
 transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err, info) {
 console.log(err, info)
 if (err)
 return res.status(500).send();
 else
 return res.status(200).send({
 status: 'OK',
 message: 'Success.',
  });
});
```

And by the way i have enabled Less Secure Apps on my gmail, again this is not the first time i implement nodemailer but it is the first time i encounter this issue...

Comment: Is this recent? have you changed the code? was it working before?. I only ask because I have also recently come across this issue.

Comment: @DanStarns Hey, actually i noticed something else now as i deployed my code to my server and called my API from my application it is working, but from localhost it is not... Maybe try this too if you can on your side

Comment: hmm, mine just randomly stopped working in production.

Comment: @DanStarns That is bad, this service must be reliable on my part because i will be using it for password recovery, i think it must be investigated further...

Comment: interesting, I don't know the answer to this. I've marked the question in the hope of someone to provide a solution. Good luck